# Anyone had issues with Smart App Control and Wixtoolset created setup package blocking uninstall when a custom action function is called?

Tags: wix

I've created an install package using the WixToolset v3.11. When run on a Windows 11 system that has Smart App Control (SAC) turned on it installs fine.  When uninstalling without rebooting after the install however SAC stops the uninstall when the uninstall operation calls the Custom Action dll.  During the install process the same Custom Action dll is called successfully.  If the system is rebooted the uninstall will perform as expected uninstalling the application successfully. The basic steps go like this:

Steps 1:

- Install the application from the setup.exe
- Without rebooting attempt to uninstall the application.

Results:

- When the uninstaller calls the Custom Action dll, SAC blocks the uninstall.

Steps 2:

- Install the application from the setup.exe
- Reboot the system after the installation is complete.
- Attempt to uninstall the application.

Results:

- The uninstall is successful.

Notes:

- All of the files in the setup package are signed correctly including the Custom Action dll, msi etc.
- The same Custom Action dll is called during install as well as uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

Similar behavior in my case was linked with the PATH system environment variable in Windows 7. Installer updates this variable. But its value doesn't change immediately. It changes after end of current session or after reboot. After that my script in folder listed in new PATH value become available.